# Reference for inequality on Frobenius/Hilbert-Schmidt matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

It is not hard to see that if ${\bf A}$ is a $d\times d$ matrix with unit determinant, $\det({\bf A})=1,$ then one has an upper bound on the Hilbert-Schmidt (Frobenius) norm of the inverse matrix ${\bf A}^{-1}$ in terms of the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of the matrix itself in the form
$$
\Vert {\bf A}^{-1}\Vert_{\bf{HS}}^2 \leq C_d \Vert {\bf A}\Vert_{\bf{HS}}^{2(d-1)}
$$
For some appropriately chosen constant $C_d.$ I am interested in the best constants.

Obviously $C_2=1$ and I computed that $C_3=\frac{1}{3}$. I believe that the best constant is $C_d=\frac{1}{d^{d-2}}$; one can obviously not do better, as the identity saturates this. I actually only need the case $d=3$, and I don't even really need the best constant, but I am curious, and my calculation for $d=3$ is a bit of a mess.

Does anyone have a reference for this inequality, ideally the best constants, or a slick proof of this?

**Update** I have done the calculation for all $d$ using Lagrange multipliers with the singular values as coordinates but I would still appreciate either a reference or a slick proof.

Answer (score 4):

We will start by proving this inequality:

> If $n\in \mathbb N$, $x_i\ge 0$, \begin{align}
> \frac1n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{x_k}\right)\prod_{k=1}^n x_k \le \left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^{n-1}
> \end{align}

I will use **induction** the inequality is trivial for $n=2$. Assume that the inequality is true for $n$ numbers and denote $s = \frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k$, $p = \prod_{k=1}^n x_k$ and $q = \frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac1{x_k}$ Since the inequality is true then $s^{n-1} \ge pq$. Let $$f(x) = \left(\frac{x + ns}{n+1}\right)^{n} - \frac{px\left(\frac1x + nq\right)}{n+1} = \left(\frac{x + ns}{n+1}\right)^{n} - \frac{p\left(1 + nqx\right)}{n+1}.$$

So $$f'(x) = n \left(\frac{x+ns}{n+1}\right)^{n-1} - \frac{npq}{n+1}$$ and for $x\ge s$,
\begin{align}
f'(x) &\ge n \left(\frac{s+ns}{n+1}\right)^{n-1} - \frac{npq}{n+1}\\
&= ns^{n-1} - \frac{n}{n+1}pq\\
&\ge pq - \frac{n}{n+1}pq\\
&= \frac1{n+1}pq \ge 0.
\end{align}

This proves that $f$ is nondecreasing on $[s, \infty)$ and if we take $x_{n+1} \ge s$ then, $$f\left(x_{n+1}\right) \ge f(s) \ge 0.$$

This ends the proof.

Now back to the original problem and let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d$ be the eigenvalues of $\mathbf A^\intercal \mathbf A$

\begin{align}
\left\|\mathbf A^{-1}\right\|^2_{\mathbf{HS}} &= \mathbf {Tr}\left(\left(\mathbf A^{-1}\right)^\intercal\mathbf A^{-1}\right)\\
&= \mathbf {Tr}\left(\left(\mathbf A^\intercal\mathbf A\right)^{-1}\right)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^d\frac1{\lambda_i}\\
&\le d\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^d \lambda_i}\left(\frac1d \sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i\right)^{d-1}\\
&\le \frac{d}{d^{d-1}} \frac{\mathbf{Tr}\left(\mathbf A^\intercal \mathbf A\right)^{d-1}}{\det\left(\mathbf A^\intercal \mathbf A\right)}\\
&= \frac{1}{d^{d-2}} \left(\left\|\mathbf A\right\|^2_{\mathbf{HS}}\right)^{d-1}
\end{align}