# Range for $\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n^2}$ under the conditions $a_1\cdots a_n=1$ and $A=a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2$ fixed

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let $A>0$ be a fixed constant and $a_1,...,a_n>0$ be such that the product $a_1\cdots a_n=1$ and that $A=a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2$.

I wonder what are the supremum and infimum values for

$$\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n^2}.$$

When $n=2$ this is clear since $\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\frac{1}{a_2^2}=a_1^2+a_2^2$ whenever $a_1a_2=1$. But for general $n$ I don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since by AM-GM $$A\geq n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^na_i^2}=n,$$ we obtain the following cases.

1. $0<A<n$. So the range of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i^2}$ it's $\varnothing$.
2. $A=n$. So the range is $\{n\}$.
3. $A>n$.

In this case we can use the Vasc's EV Method. See here https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf

Corollary 1.9, Case 1(b).

We have: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i^2}$ gets a minimal value for $0<a=a_1=a_2=...=a_{n-1}\leq a_n=b$ and

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i^2}$ gets a maximal value for $0<a=a_1\leq a_2=...=a_{n-1}=a_n=b$.

For example, for the minimum  we obtain $a^{n-1}b=1$ and $(n-1)a^2+b^2=A$, which says that $a$ it's a less root of the equation: $$(n-1)a^{2n}-Aa^{2(n-1)}+1=0$$

Answer (score -1):

> Prove that for $x_k \in (0, \infty)$, $$\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{x_k}\right) \prod_{k=1}^{n}x_k \le \left(\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^{n-1}$$

To have an upper bound apply this inequality for $x_k = a_k^2$ you will have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac1{a_k^2} \le \frac{A^{n-1}}{n^{n-2}}$$

To have a lower bound apply this inequality for $x_k = \frac1{a_k^2}$ you will have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac1{a_k^2} \ge n^{1 - \frac1{n-1}}A^{\frac1{n-1}}$$

---

If you want a proof of the first inequality look at the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4697483/468504)

Comment: In OP's question $A$ is a "*fixed constant*" so you don't get to choose the value of $A$.

Comment: I am not choosing it. I am just speaking of the equality case.

Comment: Then this doesn't answer OP's question in all other cases where $A \ne n$.